# rdf4j lucene over http

Tags: http, lucene, rdf4j

I'm having trouble using the built-in lucene index via RDF4J over HTTP.
I've followed the following steps:

1. Using rdf4j-workbench, I created a repository using the type `Native Java Store with RDFS+SPIN+Lucene`
2. On the client, I use: `repo = new HTTPRepository( <server>, <repo> );
   repo.initialize();`
3. I loaded the repository as I normally would. I see on the server there is a directory called `server/repositories/<repo>/index` which appears to contain a lucene index.
4. I run the query following the documentation here: http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/#_full_text_indexing_with_the_lucene_sail.
5. No hits are returned.
6. I move the repository and index to the local machine, and use a LuceneSail to create the repository connection.
7. Rerun the same query, and I get hits.

How do I reproduce the local results from the server over HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the HTTP connection, but in the fact that you're using the RDFS+SPIN+Lucene configuration when working on the server. I've just ran a few tests and this combination gives unexpected results even when querying it locally instead of over HTTP.

The short of it is that there appears to be a bug in that specific sail configuration (the culprit, specifically, seems to be the SPIN reasoner). Unless you specifically need that configuration, I suggest that you can work around the issue by just using a "Native store with Lucene Support" for now. I will update this answer as soon as I know more about the specifics of the bug.

Comment: I'd love to have RDFS+Lucene without SPIN, but that's not a workbench option. Native Store+Lucene will work for now. Thanks!

Comment: We can easily make that an option. Can you log a feature request in our issue tracker? https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues